# How can I set a player's scoreboard score to a player's coordinates [1.15.2]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a map in Minecraft Java Edition 1.15.2.

I would like to be able to get the X coordinate of a player and store it in a scoreboard value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished fairly easily using the `/execute store` and `/data get` commands:

```
/execute store result score <player or fake player name> <objective name> run data get entity <player> Pos[0]
```

(the `Pos` array is in the order `[X, Y, Z]`, so `Pos[0]` is the X coordinate)

Comment: I know this I found my problem answer 3 days ago

Comment: @OyunMıknatısı If you liked this answer, please click the check button to the left to let everyone know that the problem is solved.